Carrying same value in pivot columns
I have a sheet of raw data here as it pertains to opportunities



Opportunity Name
Amount
Quarter
Outcome




Opp1
$10,000
Q1
Most Likely


Opp 2
$20,000
Q1
Best Case


Opp 3
$10,000
Q2
Most Likely


Opp 4
$10,000
Q2
Best Case


Opp 5
$15,000
Q2
Most Likely



I have 10s of such entries. Now I am trying to create a pivot where the rows are the quarters followed by opportunity name. Column is the Outcome so it shows best case and most likely in the column. Now the problem I am trying to solve is that for a given opportunity if it has the outcome of most likely, the $ amount should be populated in the pivot in both best case and most likely. But if the outcome is best case, it should only show up there, not in most likely in the pivot
Here is the expected output in the pivot. Please note /i had to manually create a pivot like table but all of this needs to ideally happen within a pivot.


Can you showcase the expected output as well for the given test data?!

Edited and added expected output.

Are you looking to get this done via formula or pivot table feature?

Pivot table feature.

Then why did you tag  Google-sheets-formula? Note that it may not be possible with pivot table feature

It is difficult to get your expected output using the pivot table feature because the Q1 and Q2 values in the pivot table are calculated as the sum of the grand total. This calculation method is directly reflected from your raw data, which causes the difficulty in achieving the desired output using the pivot table feature. That’s why it's expected to get the $ amount populated in the pivot individually, which is in the Best Case or Most Likely part.

This presentation of data doesn't make much sense to me but I think this is what you are describing using query.
Assuming data is in Columns A,B,C,D, exactly as shown in your example, and all columns are formatted for Currency rounded. (results on right, with main formula in cell E1)

=query(

{QUERY(
A2:D, 
"select Col1, Col2, Col2+0, Col3, Col4 where Col4 = 'Most Likely' label Col1 
'', Col2 '', Col2+0 '', Col3 '', Col4 ''");

QUERY(A2:D, "select Col1, Col2, 0, Col3, Col4 where Col4 = 'Best Case' 
label Col1 '', Col2 '', 0 '', Col3 '', Col4 ''")}, 

"select Col4, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col2+Col3 where Col1 is not null order by 
Col4 label Col4 'Quarter', Col1 'Opportunity', Col2 'Best Case', Col3 
'Most Likely', Col2+Col3 'Grand Total'")


You could, in theory, split and stitch this with more querying to get the Q1 Totals rows, but it's a bit messy and I would suggest reconsidering how you log/store the data or how you want it presented.
